# Firebase Crashlytics do not sync with my android project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to start Firebase Crashlytics in my android project but for some reason the crashlytics dashboard do not refresh after running the project in a real device, I can not get past this window [image: Screen shot from firebase console], I also wait for days but nothing happened.
Here is the build.gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir

}
```

and the build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.0.2'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':wheel-release')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.14'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If no crash has occured, it is normal that nothing is showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem when i updated Firebase Crash Reporting to Crashlytics.

Try this:

-Update your google-services.json file from Firebase Console

-Add these lines to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" 
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

-After edit generate a crash in your app

Answer (score 2):

## Before

[image]

AFAIK Fabric is deprecated. So in my case adding this meta-data worked

```
<meta-data 
   android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" 
   android:value="true" />
```

## After:

[image]

### Where to add  in AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<application>
    <meta-data/>
    <activity/>
</application>
```

Comment: Hey still not updated can you help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I removed from AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="API Key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in order not to "upgrade" into the wrong direction:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false"/>
<!-- <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value=""/> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to manifest

```
<meta-data 
android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" 
android:value="true" />
```